# Null в DBRef list, mongodb, spring data reactive

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data

решил попробовать котлин в реальном проекте, заодно пощупать монго и спринг, вроде все понятно и просто, но столкнулся с проблемой, когда создаю объект Lecturer, то в поле subjects, получаю лист c null-ми. Самое главное в доке спринга есть такой пример но с джавой, что не так с котлин кодом?

```
@Document(collection = "subjects") class Subject(
        @Field var fullName: String,
        @Field var simpleName: String = fullName,
        @DBRef var groups: MutableList<Group?> = mutableListOf(),
        @Id var id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
)

@Document(collection = "lecturers") class Lecturer(
        fio: String,
        password: String,
        phone: Int = -1,
        email: String = "",
        @DBRef var subjects: Set<Subject>,
        id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
) : User(phone, email, fio, password, id)
```

Может такой результат из-за того, что классы без тела?

Answer (score 0):

Ответ оказался прост, я использлвал Reactiviti, а с ними почемуто сылки не работают, в обычном режиме все сразу заработало. П.с. класы данных были переписаны на джаве, так что тут язык котлин не причем.